# Тестирование JavaScript

Tags: javascript, тестирование, юнит-тесты

Так вот: как ПРАВИЛЬНО тестировать javascript? Типа модульных тестов и тому подобное...

Comment: зависит от кода... и от разработчиков... покажите что хотите протестировать

Comment: например, слайдер который ведёт себя по-разному, в зависимости от количества содержимого...

Comment: Что хотите получить в результате тестов?

Comment: Секрет мироздания хочу получить! :)



А что хотят от тестов? Как минимум пройден или нет.

Comment: Лично мне хватает встроенных средств chrome

Comment: дебаг и тестирование - разные вещи

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Можно работать с [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) при модульном тестировании практически любого JavaScript, не обязательно только jQuery.
2. Можно работать с [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) при системном тестировании веб-сайтов, в частности и JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет об отладке, то https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/ установите, нажмете F12, вкладка - Консоль, перегрузить страницу

Answer (score 1):

Цитирую из книги Дэвида Флэнагана "**JavaScript - Подробное руководство**".

> Если вам постоянно приходится
> сталкиваться с ошибками в
> JavaScriptсценариях, вероятно, вас
> заинтересует настоящий отладчик
> **JavaScript**. В **Internet Explorer**
> можно воспользоваться отладчиком
> **Microsoft Script Debugger**, в **Firefox** –
> модулем расширения, известным под
> названием **Venkman**. Описание этих
> инструментов выходит далеко за рамки
> темы этой книги, но вы без труда
> найдете его в Интернете,
> воспользовавшись какойнибудь
> поисковой системой. Еще один инструмент, который, строго говоря, не
> является отладчиком, – это **jslint**; он
> способен отыскивать распространенные ошибки в JavaScript-коде программ
> (http://jslint.com).

Comment: Книга 2008 г. выпуска, за это время ой как много всего нового появилось)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы работаете с проектом на Java, то можете использовать JUnit и гонять с помощью встроенного в Java интерпретатора JavaScript (Mozilla Rhino).

Answer (score 0):

Для тестирования webkit based браузеров - **[phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/)**